# How to replace a pattern in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string, erb

I built a page that is rendered differently depending on `params`. The logic is something like this:

```
<% if params[:x] == "1" %>
  <!--render version A-->
<% elsif params[:x] == "2" %>
  <!--render version B-->
<% elsif params[:x] == "3" %>
  <!--render version C-->
<% end %>
```

I want each version to have two links which link to the other two versions, so the urls should have different params. I have a url string `original_url`, which is:

```
"localhost:3000/page?x=1"
```

and want to replace its parameter depending on `params`. The other two versions should be:

```
"localhost:3000/page?x=2"
"localhost:3000/page?x=3"
```

How can I eliminate the pattern `?x=[number]` from `original_url` and replace it with something else?

For version 1, I could do

```
request.original_url.sub("?x=1", "?x=2")
```

and then

```
request.original_url.sub("?x=1", "?x=3")
```

but then that wouldn't work on the other two versions.

Comment: Why do you need to replace this? Please explain your use case because you could obviously use something like `request.original_url.gsub(/\?x=./,'?x=YOUR_NUMBER_HERE')`

Comment: @engineersmnky I included it in the original question, but somebody edited it out for some reason... I added it back.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do this for the links

```
<%= ([1,2,3]- [params[:x]]).each do |link_number| %>
   <%= link_to "Version #{link_number}", "/page?x=#{link_number}" %>
<% end %>
```

This way everytime the page is loaded the link to the other 2 versions will exist.

You could handle the partials through the controller (which seems better) or use something like:

```
<%= render "version_#{['A','B','C'][params[:x] - 1]}" %>
```

Without a better understanding of the problem I cannot assist beyond this point.