# Can I pass params into a controller path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink, parameters, controller

I have a few different links, that do the same thing except for one minor difference. Is it possible to link them all to the same path, but with different params that change the behavior of that one minor difference in the controller?

I was thinking of something like this:

**view**

```
<%= link_to "Link-A", link_path(@user), @x = 1 %>
<%= link_to "Link-B", link_path(@user), @x = 2 %>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def link
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  #code that should be executed for both links
  if @x == 1
    #do something
  elsif @x == 2
    #do something else
  end
end
```

I know this specific code probably isn't even close to being correct, but hopefully it makes clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Did you try, `link_path(@user, x: 1)`? I think that will pass the value in the `params` hash (`params[:x]`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace a pattern in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015390/how-to-replace-a-pattern-in-a-string) Since you asked this one too.

Comment: @engineersmnky They're completely different questions...this one is asking how to access params in the controller, that one was asking how to replace a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**View**:

```
<%= link_to "Link-A", link_path(@user, x: 1) %>
<%= link_to "Link-B", link_path(@user, x: 2) %>
```

**Controller**:

```
def link
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  x = params[:x]

  #code that should be executed for both links

  if x == 1
    #do something
  elsif x == 2
    #do something else
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should add your param as an option to your path like so:

```
<%= link_to "Link-A", link_path(@user, x: "1") %>
```

then in **controller** you can do:

```
...
@input = params[:x]
if @input ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In the view, send also the control params

```
<%= link_to 'Link', request.parameters.merge({:x => 'special'}) %>
```

In the controller, check the params then start then logic.

```
if params.fetch(:x)
  # A different logic
end
```